# #N/A VLOOKUP issue

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have been trying to use other questions already asked on SO but unfortunately I can't resolve my issue.

With reference to my excel document (link below) I am trying to copy Columns C, D and E in spreadsheet '2007', into columns I, J and K in FTSE All-Share spreadsheet. However, I am trying to do this based on similar dates in Column B ('2007') and Column I ('FTSE All-share'). Unfortunately there are dates missing.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_3GWcee1eHXblhNVUxRQ0E2Ync/edit?usp=sharing

I have been attempting to use the following VLOOKUP formula, but it keeps returning #N/A.

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,'2007'!B:E,2,FALSE)
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I should add, the dates missing means i cant just copy and paste, and, importantly, it doesnt matter if not all of spreadsheet '2007' is copied into 'FTSE All-share'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `J2` to `=VLOOKUP(text(I2,"yyyy-mm-dd"),'2007'!B:C,2,FALSE)` and paste down. You attempted to put in the correct formula, but your `I2` is a data and `'2007'!B` is a text.